# Socket not printing out data

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

I'm trying to test my chat client system which is made with client threads and each thread has a socket with which it connects to the server.Now I am trying to run a test which waits for 3 client threads to connect by choosing a room( the name of the room is USA) and then send a message to each other however when I run the test 2 scenarios happen:

1.all 3 threads start ,but 2 out of 3 print what they recieved,after that nothing happens and the test is stuck,@AfterSuite doesn't even run

2.all 3 threads start 2 out of 3 print what they recieved ,the third thread doesn't print anything however new 3 threads are started (3 new sockets are made),at the end all 6 are closed

This isn't the behaviour I expect from both cases I expect all 3 to print what they recieved and @AfterSuite to run successfully,The code worked on my main pc but now I am on different and it doesn't seem to behave as expected, which I cannot figure out why,here is the code:

```
public class NotUniqueMessagesTest {
final int NUMBER_OF_SOCKETS = 3;
Server server = new Server();

List<Socket> allsockets = new ArrayList<>();

private final CyclicBarrier barrier = new CyclicBarrier(NUMBER_OF_SOCKETS);
Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        server.start();

    }
});

@BeforeSuite
public void startServer() {

    t.start();
    System.out.println("System out println" + server.getSocket());

    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@AfterSuite
public void stopServer() {

    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    server.stop();
}

@Test
public void testMessagesReceived() throws IOException {

    System.out.println(server.getChatroomSize("Bulgaria"));

    for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_SOCKETS; i++) {

        Runnable r = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                try {
                    barrier.await();
                } catch (InterruptedException | BrokenBarrierException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }

                try {
                    Socket socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 3000);
                    allsockets.add(socket);
                    final PrintWriter stream = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);

                    stream.println("USA");
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

        };

        new Thread(r).start();
    }

    while (server.getChatroomSize("USA") != NUMBER_OF_SOCKETS) {

    }

    System.out.println("FINISHED WAITING ALL CLIENTS HAVE COME");
    for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_SOCKETS; i++) {
        final PrintWriter stream = new PrintWriter(allsockets.get(i).getOutputStream(), true);

        stream.println("All say what I say");
    }

    int totalMessages = 2 + 2 * (NUMBER_OF_SOCKETS - 1);

    for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_SOCKETS; i++) {
        final BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(allsockets.get(i).getInputStream()));

        for (int j = 0; j < totalMessages; j++) {
            String line = reader.readLine();
            System.out.println(line);

        }

        System.out.println();

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

1. It is not a good practice synchronizing through an empty loop:

   `while (server.getChatroomSize("USA") != NUMBER_OF_SOCKETS) {
   }`

... for this will raise the CPU near the 100%, causing some blocking in the rest of the threads.

Ideally, synchronization between threads should be done through the *wait-notify* paradigm. Oh, OK: I see you are here synchronizing two different programs: The testing program is waiting for a certain condition in the main program to be true. Well, I recommend you to fulfil that empty loop so that it won't monopolize the CPU time. At least, something like this:

```
`while (server.getChatroomSize("USA") != NUMBER_OF_SOCKETS) {
    Thread.sleep(10);
    Thread.yield();
}`
```

2. Early closing the streams through a try-with-resources instruction is also a good practice:

   `try(PrintWriter stream = ...)
   {
       ...
   }`

   (Idem readers.)
3. Please review your code to simplify unnecessary complex expressions like this:

   `2 + 2 * (NUMBER_OF_SOCKETS - 1);`
4. I don't see clearly the intention of this condition:

   `for (int j = 0; j < totalMessages; j++)`

By the previous program logic, I understand that just ONE message is written per socket. But in this loop, `totalMessages==2`, so why to expect two messages on each socket?